# Get max value from another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problems with some query. I need to get max value and product_name from that query:

```
select
    products.product_name,
    sum(product_invoice.product_amount) as total_amount
from 
    product_invoice
inner join 
    products on product_invoice.product_id = products.product_id
inner join 
    invoices on product_invoice.invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id
where 
    month(invoices.invoice_date) = 2
group by 
    products.product_name
```

This query returns a result like this:

```
product_name  | total_amount
--------------+--------------
      chairs  |  70              
      ladders | 500  
      tables  | 150
```

How to get from this: `ladders 500`?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Select product_name,max(total_amount) from(
      select
      products.product_name,
      sum(product_invoice.product_amount) as total_amount
    from product_invoice
      inner join products
        on product_invoice.product_id = products.product_id
      inner join invoices
        on product_invoice.invoice_id = invoices.invoice_id
    where month(invoices.invoice_date) = 2
    group by products.product_name
    ) outputTable
```

Comment: This isn't even syntactically correct.  Why is it the accepted answer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, that's not corrent, i've just taken the subquery and rewrite it for my task. I've not published the answer cause it seems a little silly.

Comment: @AlexNemet . . . The subquery is basically my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `order by` and `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
select p.product_name,
       sum(pi.product_amount) as total_amount
from product_invoice pi inner join
     products p
     on pi.product_id = p.product_id inner join
     invoices i
     on pi.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
where month(i.invoice_date) = 2  -- shouldn't you have the year here too?
group by p.product_name
order by total_amount
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support the ANSI-standard `fetch first` clause.  You may need to use `limit`, `select top`, or some other construct.

Note that I have also introduced table aliases -- they make the query easier to write and to read.  Also, if you are selecting the month, shouldn't you also be selecting the year?

In older versions of SQL Server, you would use `select top 1`:

```
select top (1) p.product_name,
       sum(pi.product_amount) as total_amount
from product_invoice pi inner join
     products p
     on pi.product_id = p.product_id inner join
     invoices i
     on pi.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
where month(i.invoice_date) = 2  -- shouldn't you have the year here too?
group by p.product_name
order by total_amount;
```

To get all rows with the top amount, use `SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES . . .`.

Comment: what if more than one row is having max value as 500

Comment: @JayShankarGupta Yes. I haven't thought about it. Then i will have wrong data. Thanks

Comment: Check my answer @AlexNemet

Comment: @AlexNemet . . . As explained in the last line of my answer, you would use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`, if you wanted all products tied for the top.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, then `TOP` can offer a solution:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    p.product_name,
    SUM(pi.product_amount) AS total_amount
FROM product_invoice pi
INNER JOIN products p
    ON pi.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN invoices i
    ON pi.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
WHERE
    MONTH(i.invoice_date) = 2
GROUP BY
    p.product_name
ORDER BY
    SUM(pi.product_amount) DESC;
```

Note: If there could be more than one product tied for the top amount, and you want all ties, then use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`, e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
... (the same query I have above)
```