# Need to get MAX selling price in last 4 transaction

Tags: mysql, max

I have a `table` named sellingDetails.

Table Data is as follows

```
+--------+----------------+
|  id    |   sellingPrice |
+--------+----------------+
|  1     |  35000         |
|  2     |  40000         |
|  3     |  30000         |
|  4     |  25000         |
|  5     |  35000         |
|  6     |  33000         |
|  7     |  25000         |
+--------+----------------+
```

When I query

```
SELECT id, sellingPrice 
FROM sellingDetails 
ORDER BY id DESC limit 0, 4
```

The above query outputs:

```
+--------+----------------+
|  id    |   sellingPrice |
+--------+----------------+
|  7     |  25000         |
|  6     |  33000         |
|  5     |  35000         |
|  4     |  25000         |
+--------+----------------+
```

Out of the above result how I can get the `MAX` result i.e. 35000.
I tried using `MAX(sellingprice)` but it didn't work.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221560/get-max-value-from-another-query) is very near to mine but it has joins whereas mine is a single table

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wco1hYMGXKJqWmrPWhqzGz/0)

If I use the below query

```
SELECT MAX(sellingprice) FROM sellingdetails
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 4;
```

I get output as 40000 which is not intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your existing query as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and then determine the maximum value from it.

```
SELECT MAX(dt.sellingPrice)
FROM 
(
  SELECT sellingPrice 
  FROM sellingDetails 
  ORDER BY id DESC limit 0, 4
) dt
```

**Result**

```
| MAX(dt.sellingPrice) |
| -------------------- |
| 35000                |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wco1hYMGXKJqWmrPWhqzGz/2)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! waiting for min. time to accept the answer.